# Farben als Neutrum vs. Femininum - regionale Verwendung?

Tags: gender

Werden Farbbezeichnungen als Substantive verwendet, sind sie im Allgemeinen neutral:

- Das Blau des Himmels ist wunderschön.
- Das Rot ihrer Haare bildete einen starken Konstrast zum Weiß ihrer blassen Haut.

etc.

Dem gegenüber ist mir jedoch auch die Verwendung als Femininum geläufig, die zumindest in Südwestdeutschland verbreitet zu sein scheint:

- Hast du noch eine Blau? Meine ist alle.
- Diese Gelb ist viel heller als jene.

etc.

Meinem Sprachgefühl nach verläuft die Abgrenzung recht scharf entlang der Linie, ob es sich um den visuellen Eindruck einer Farbe handelt (neutral) oder ob es sich um eine greifbare Farbe mit dem Zweck, etwas anderes einzufärben, handelt (feminin). Das heißt:

Beschreibt man also z.B. die Farbe, die eine grüne Linie auf einem Blatt Papier hat, wäre es "das Grün"; bezieht man sich aber auf den "Werkstoff" bzw. insbesondere das Zeichenwerkzeug, ist es "die Grün". Entsprechend bietet der Baumarkt unter anderem einen besonderen Gelbton zum Wände Streichen an (das Gelb), was man dann aber im Eimer nach Hause trägt, ist "die Gelb". Der Gegensatz lässt sich auch in einem Satz gegenüberstellen; "Das Rot dieser Rot ist besonders kräftig." nehme ich als idiomatisch wahr - das erste "Rot" bezieht sich hier auf den Farbton, das zweite auf die diesen Farbton besitzende Zeichenressource.

Freilich ist das eine umgangssprachliche Verwendung, denn in formellerem Kontext würde ich ohnehin zu einer Konstruktion wie "der grüne Stift" bzw. "die gelbe Dispersionsfarbe" tendieren.

**Ist diese Unterscheidung ein Regionalismus, und falls ja, wo ist er gebräuchlich?** Meine Versuche, Informationen darüber zu finden, waren bislang leider erfolglos, weil sich entsprechende Suchanfragen sehr einfach als Frage nach dem grammatikalischen Geschlecht des Worts "Farbe" selber fehlinterpretieren lassen.

Comment: Vielleicht kommt man mit einer case-sensitiven Suchmaschine und Suchen wie `"diese Gelb"`, etc. weiter...

Comment: Irgendwie kommt mir das als Kontraktion von "die gelbe Farbe" vor.

Comment: @orithena: Mit Sicherheit geht das darauf zurück. Wobei aber auch "die Farbe" dann eine Bedeutungserweiterung erlebt. Denn während "die Farbe" (als Substanz) wohl eine zum Einfärben gedachte Flüssigkeit bezeichnet, tue ich mich schon schwer damit, einen konkreten gelben Stift als "die gelbe Farbe" zu beschreiben - "die Gelb" scheint mir dagegen durchaus treffend. Und das lässt sich auf weitere Werkstoffe ausdehnen - auch einen Vorrat an gelben Bügelperlchen würde ich beispielsweise als "die Gelb" bezeichnen (niemals aber als "die gelbe Farbe", dann schon eher als "die (pl.) gelben Perlchen").

Comment: Ich kenne das, wenn 5 Kinder im frühen Vorschulalter um einen Tisch rumsitzen und malen (ja, aus SW-D). Wenn ich jetzt aber statistisch sagen müsste, dass "m/f/n" in irgendeiner Häufigkeit vorkommen würden, dann würde ich sagen: vollkommen gleichverteilt. Meine Vermutung: Die Kinder haben noch kein sprachliches Konzept für den Sexus eines abstrakten Dings wie einer Farbe und probieren einfach irgendwas.

Comment: @tofro Nicht nur Kinder, auch manche Erwachsene haben immer noch kein Gefühl für Sprache ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Community-Regional-Atlas:

| Region | Status | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rheinland | unbekannt | [HalvarF](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/44671/halvarf), [Tilman Schmidt](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/18273/tilman-schmidt) |
| Schleswig-Holstein | unbekannt | HalvarF |
| Mannheim | unbekannt | HalvarF |
| Württemberg | unbekannt | [Tilman Schmidt](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/18273/tilman-schmidt) |
| Graz | für Stifte o.Ä. | [phipsgabler](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/44671/halvarf) |
| Sachsen | unbekannt | [jonathan.scholbach](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/15393/jonathan-scholbach) |
| Wiener Raum | unbekannt | bakunin |
| Frankfurt/Südhessen | unbekannt | bakunin |
| Salzburg (Land) | unbekannt | bakunin |
| Thüringen | unbekannt | bakunin, planetmaker |
| Niedersachsen | unbekannt | planetmaker |

Eine andere denkbare Erklärung wäre noch, dass ein ungenanntes feminines Nomen mitgemeint ist, zum Beispiel Kreide, Sprühdose, Tube, oder auch "Farbe" im Sinn eines Farbdöschens im Tuschkasten.

> Hast du eine Aquamarinblau?

wäre dann z.B. kurz für

> Hast du eine Farbe (in) Aquamarinblau?

Das wäre aber beschränkt auf Situationen, in denen so ein feminines Nomen irgenwie zutrifft. Bei einem Eimer Farbe oder einem Buntstift oder Filzstift sehe ich das nicht.

Comment: Bei einem Eimer Farbe ist das feminine Nomen freilich eben "die Farbe" (im Sinn der flüssigen Farbe, die im Eimer ist). Bei einem Buntstift sehe ich aber in der Tat kein wirklich speziell auf das Objekt bezogene Nomen, weshalb ich davon ausgehe, dass sich letztendlich alles auf die (aufmalbare) Farbe bezieht.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn diese Formulierung überhaupt funktionieren soll, dann höchstens als sogenannte Ellipse - die Auslassung eines (selbstverständlichen) Teils einer Konstruktion.

> Hast du mal eine?

Kann zB., wenn davor im Kontext Zigaretten erwähnt werden, durchaus - wenn auch umgangssprachlich - OK sein:

> Ich habe keine Kippen mehr. Hast du mal eine?

Dasselbe hier, allerdings müßte dann das "Blau" zu "blaue" oder "blauen" werden, damit es mit dem weggelassenen "Farbe", "Stift", etc. korrespondiert. In der Form, wie @O._R._Mapper das beschreibt, kann ich es mir nicht vorstellen.

Comment: Das ist leider keine sehr fundierte Antwort. Die Frage ist ja explizi, ob es sich um einen Regionalismus handeln könnte. Hast du dazu irgendwelche Daten?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Wenn Du mir sagst, wie "Daten" zu "es gibt keinen solchen Regionalismus" aussehen sollten, dann werde ich sie gerne beibringen. Soll ich die Nicht-Treffer in Google zählen?

Comment: Es kann durchaus eine Ellipse aus "die Farbe Blau" sein.

Comment: Man könnte zum Beispiel Menschen verschiedener Regiolekte befragen, und dann eine Liste von Regionen anfertigen, in denen diese Konstruktion nicht existiert oder aber existiert. Damit hätte man zwar auch nicht die Existenz in allen Regionen ausgeschlossen, aber man wäre doch einen großen Schritt weiter. Wenn ich die Antwort richtig verstehe, schließt du aus, dass eine solche Formulierung überhaupt denkbar ist. Auf welcher Grundlage?

Comment: Der Nachweis der Nicht-Existenz ist prinzipiell (fast) unmöglich. Weise mal nach, dass es KEINE rosa Elefanten gibt. Da werden sicher die nächsten 5 Leute sagen, dass es die nicht gäbe - aber ein Nachweis ist das noch lange nicht.